# indexing in tensorflow slower than gather

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-xla

I am trying to index into a  tensor to get a slice or single element from 1d tensors. I find that there is  significant performance difference when using the `numpy` way of indexing `[:]` and `slice vs tf.gather`  (almost 30-40% ).

Also I observe that `tf.gather` has significant overhead when used on scalars (looping over unstacked tensor) as opposed to tensor . Is this a known issue ?

example code (inefficient) :

```
for node_idxs in graph.nodes():
    node_indice_list = tf.unstack(node_idxs)
    result = []
    for nodeid in node_indices_list:
        x = tf.gather(..., nodeid)
        y = tf.gather(..., nodeid)
        result.append(tf.mul(x,y))
return tf.stack(result)
```

as opposed to
example code (efficient) :

```
for node_idxs in graph.nodes():
    x = tf.gather(..., node_idxs)
    y = tf.gather(..., node_idxs)
return tf.mul(x, y)
```

I understand that the first inefficient implementation is doing more work of unstacking, stacking and then looping and more gather operations, but i was not expecting 100x slowdown when the order of nodes i am operating on is few hundred nodes (is unstacking and overhead of gather on single scalar that slow, in first case i have many more gather operation each operating on single element as opposed to tensor of offsets) . Are there faster way of indexing , i tried numpy and slice which turned out to be slower than gather.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code doesn't really compare gather vs Numpy indexing - it compares vectorized indexing (tf.gather) vs looped indexing (Python "for" loop). No surprise that looping is slow.

Note that Numpy-like indexing `tensor[idxs]` is anyway restricted in Tensorflow:

> Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and
> scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices

So use `tf.gather` for general applications.