# How to efficiently restrict tensorflow model output?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sparse-matrix

I have a model, e.g.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(10,10,1),input_shape=(100,)),
    keras.layers.Convolution2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='relu')
])
```

After it's trained, I would only like to do compute a subset of the outputs, e.g.

```
out = model(x)[:,3,5]
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently so that I'm not computing all of the outputs? Ideally, I'd like to define a new model that takes x and the output indices only computes them, e.g.

```
out = new_model(x,out_indices)
```

Comment: With this model, you get a [None,12,12,1] tensor. Which dimensions do you want to do indexing on?

Comment: The output will be [batch_size, h,w,depth]. I will create a list out_indices [(3,5,4), (2,4,8),...]. I want the model to only run the computation that's needed for these output indices. Is there some way that I can trace these outputs and the make the model do sparse computation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

This is your first model. Note that I removed the `Reshape` layer and directly specified the `input_shape` for the `Convolution2DTranspose` layer.

```
model = models.Sequential([    
    layers.Convolution2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,10,1))
])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

This is probably the bit you're interested in. You get an `(None, 12, 12, 1)` output from the previous model. Here, you are passing a batch or 4 dimensional indices (one element for each dimension of the previous model output).

```
inp = layers.Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32')
out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather_nd(model.output, x))(inp)
model2 = models.Model(inputs=[inp, model.input], outputs=out)
model2.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model2.summary()
```

Now you can get the values of any indices you pass to the model.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(1,10, 10, 1))
ind = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0]], dtype='int32')
y = model2.predict([ind, x])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I get this error when I run the code. **ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
     x sizes: 2, 1
     Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.**

Comment: Can you tell me in which line you get the error and which TF version you're using (I used TF 1.15)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code works in 1.15. However, I don't think the code is efficiently computing the output. The run-times are pretty much the same as when I compute everything and then index into the array. I bumped the input shape to (1000,1000) to see this. Your code should be way faster than computing everything and the indexing into the output.

Comment: @lab_rat So what do you mean by `when I compute everything and then index into the array`.

Comment: I mean out = model.predict(x)[inds]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't expect it to be faster than that. As far as I know, `gather_nd` is a slow operation (Some evidence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048235/indexing-in-tensorflow-slower-than-gather)). So if you want performance, I suggest using slicing instead of narrow indexing.